# Android: How to get Song title and Artist name from Shoutcast?

Tags: android, shoutcast

i know this question is already asked by may users, but none of the answer are found working for me.

i want to get song title from shout cast URL i.e

visit http://50.97.215.122:8775, but i am unable to get song title. pleaes help me the way i can do.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean the other answers don't work for you?  Which have you tried?  What was the outcome?  This question is asked on a near-weekly basis.  The answer hasn't changed in a decade.

Answer (score 4):

The following pages give you:

```
Current song:     http://yourstream:port/currentsong?sid=#
Last 20 songs:    http://yourstream:port/played.html?sid#
Next songs:       http://yourstream:port/nextsongs?sid=#
```

Note: `nextsongs?sid=#` must be supported by the player which feeds the stream. `sc_trans` supports this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on the same problem. I used streamscraper (see: http://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/) to obtain the required metadata. Please see the project homepage, the provided example works perfectly for me.

And yes, I used it on android.